# Cloaking device on the Defiant

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Is there any explanation as to:

1. How the Defiant used a cloaking device, after the Romulan "minder" died?
2. How the Sao Paolo had another cloaking device?

I looked through this site, and found no answers.

Comment: Just cause the minder died, doesn't mean no one can work out how to use it.  Remember, Star Fleet has those engineers that can make "replicators from rocks".  Also, Star Fleet has always had knowledge of cloaking tech.  They just never used it because of the treaty with the Romulans.

Comment: There are two distinct questions here.

Comment: Are we certain the Sao Paulo even *had* a cloaking device? Memory alpha makes no mention of a cloaking device ([1](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Sao_Paulo)), and claims (without citation) that it in fact was not equipped with one ([2](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Defiant_class#Cloaking_device)).

Comment: Please separate these into two separate questions because they raise distinct points, plus more rep!

Comment: New question regarding the Sao Paulo and cloaking device: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/156643/24826

Answer (score 4):

1. The "minder" was there to enforce the terms of the treaty. Remember, the Federation-Romulan treaty forbid the Federation from having cloaking technology. Per the terms of the agreement on the Defiant, they could only use the cloaking device in the Gamma quadtrant. We know that [the Federation was quite capable of building cloaking devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pegasus_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)).
2. The *Sao Paolo* never had a cloaking device. When it was renamed to Defiant, [the Romulans installed it as part of the intel agreement](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(NX-74205)_(I))

   > An agreement (by way of a treaty) signed between Starfleet and the Romulan Star Empire allowed a cloaking device to be **installed aboard the Defiant** in return for intelligence about the Dominion and that it only be used in the Gamma Quadrant.

Comment: Ad.2. - I believe you have mistakenely taken the quote from the original USS Defiant (NX-74205), which indeed had a cloacking device installed, while USS Sao Paolo (renamed to USS Defiant) was a different ship with reg. number NCC-75633. Sometimes the registry for the latter Defiant has been shown improperly, still the second Defiant (commissioned in 2375) has never had a cloaking device.